# Amazon S3 upload works with one credentials but not other

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two S3 buckets under two different accounts. Permissions and CORS setting of both buckets are same. 
Regions of two buckets are as following (First one working)

1. Region: Asia Pacific (Singapore) (ap-southeast-1) works
2. Region: US East (Ohio) (us-east-2) does not work

I created Upload script with Node.js and supplied region plus following

```
Key : __XXXX__
secret: __XXXXX____,
bucket: _____XXXX__
'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
ACL: 'public-read'
```

Code works fine with first, uploaded files is also accessible publicly. But with 2nd account(Region: us-east-2), script runs successfully and return URL also, but when I look in bucket there is no upload and url is saying permission denied which means resource is not available. Strange things are

1. Why URL is returned if file is not uploaded in bucket?
2. Why same code does not working for other account,

I tried AWS documentation also but that seems like it's not written for human like me. Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: AWS doesn't return a URL for uploaded objects so your code, or a library that you're using, is doing that (perhaps incorrectly). You mentioned two AWS accounts - are the credentials that you are using valid for both of the AWS accounts you are uploading to, and do they have the correct set of S3 permissions?

Comment: *"url is saying permission denied which means resource is not available"*  Please don't rephrase or summarize error messages.  Show the **exact** error.

Comment: Also, Singapore is a much older region than Ohio, thus Singapore would work with code using either Signature V2 or V4, while Ohio supports Sig V4 exclusively.  Code that works in Ohio would work in Singapore, but the opposite is not necessarily true.  Not seeing your code, we can't say whether this might be a factor.

Answer (score 0):

> script runs successfully and return URL also, but when I look in bucket there is no upload

If you can really see no resources in the bucket, then the upload really failed (I've seen too many scripts just ignoring any error response) or the upload is executed to different place than you expect.  Care to share the script?

> and url is saying permission denied which means resource is not available

Unfortunatelly that's something you have find out yourself. If the object is in the bucket, it has public access,  correct cors settings, then maybe the url is not correct.